# Firebase: make a query case insensitive

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

We have Angular/Ionic app.
One of the fields that we ask during registration is `email`.
Then we save the data to the `User` collection.

We also check if the email is already used. Example query:

```
firestore
    .collection("User")
    .where("email", "==", email)
    .get()
```

The issue is that firebase is case-sensitive.
For example, `testemail@gmail.com` and `TESTemail@gmail.com` will be considered as two different emails.

We have not lowercase an email during registration previously so this case-sensitive behavior potentially can cause issues.
Any advice on how we can lowercase email in a request and in DB when checking if an email already exists?

Answer (score 1):

You have to update all the documents in your collection to either modify the existing `email` field value in such a way it is in lower case or keep the `email` field value as it is and create another field, e.g. `emailLowerCase` in which you save the value of the `email` field in lower case.

In other words, there is no way to adapt the query in such a way it returns the different variations of the email values.